# Проблема с магазином скинов в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

делаю игрушку на юнити, начал разрабатывать магазин и столкнулся с проблемой - при попытке скроллинга как у меня после окончания списка все ломается. Как это можно исправить? Я пробовал делать ресет int переменной в разных случаях, это не помогало, само значение меняю в другом скрипте он и основной скрипт смены указаны ниже

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class ShopController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int CurrentStyle = 1;
    public Sprite[] StyleFront;//в этом списке лежат 3 спрайта для тех трех обьектов, в случае если в списке спрайтов не остается все ломается к чертям собачим
    public GameObject[] StyleObj;//в этом списке лежат 3 обьекта у которых я меняю спрайт
    private void Update()
    {
        StyleObj[0].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = StyleFront[CurrentStyle];
        StyleObj[1].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = StyleFront[CurrentStyle+1];
        StyleObj[2].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = StyleFront[CurrentStyle-1];
    }
}
```

И второй скрипт

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class ClickChanger : MonoBehaviour
{
public ShopController shp;
public bool isLeft;

public void Click()
{
    if (isLeft)
    {
        shp.CurrentStyle = shp.CurrentStyle -= 1;
    }
    if (!isLeft)
    {
        shp.CurrentStyle = shp.CurrentStyle += 1;
        
    }
}
```

}

Я перепробовал просто все, ничего не выходит, по сути на третьем должно все при нажатии кнопки выглядеть как на центральном скриншоте, но выглядит это все как на первом[image: 3][image: 2]
[image: скрин при запуске]

Comment: `shp.CurrentStyle = shp.CurrentStyle -= 1;` это еще что такое?                                                           Надо так `shp.CurrentStyle  -=  1;`

Comment: Bulson мне так удобней, это просто изменение значения

Comment: неправильно отображаются боковый(следующий и предыдущий скины)

Comment: спрайты из массива не отображаются в правильном порядке

Comment: цвета из списка путаются и отображаются в неправильном пордке

Comment: @Деррил - за идиотов - жалоба на комментарий. Строчить капсом нужно, потому что вы обязаны знать правила ресурса, а кидаться - я не кидался. Теперь по вопросу: а где код самого скроллера? Вы, я так понимаю, делаете горизонтальный скроллер, вы это делаете с компонента [Scroller](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.Scroller.html)? Если да, то в нем можно задать значение сдвига скроллера через value. Но вроде, если скроллер отмечен как interactable, то его можно сразу двигать руками без проблем. Советую добавить скрин того, что происходит. Да, а как данный код относится к скроллу?

Comment: @МаксимФисман скроллер указан в первом скрипте, через значения я меняю спрайты в нужных обьектах из списка, а во втором по нажатию кнопок изменяю само значение

Comment: Сразу скажу, что делать GetComponent в Update - нельзя, тем более трижды. В общем скроллер вы делаете не через Scroller. Ну ошибка может возникать из-за того, что вы выходите за рамки массива.У вас в StyleObj 3 элемента, также в StyleFront. Если мы нажмем на кнопку вправо, то CurrentStyle станет равно 2, и в следующем фрейме вы будете получать StyleFront[3], а там всего 3 элемента, а вы получаете уже **четвертый**. То же самое в левую сторону. Вы будете получать StyleFront[-1], а минус первого элемента массива бывает по-моему только в питоне

Comment: @МаксимФисман да, ошибка с массивом есть, но проблема не в этом, [-1] элемента массива это получение последнего элемента, скрин к комментарию не крепится попробую сейчас отредактировать сам пост

Comment: @МаксимФисман приложил скрины,возможно так понятнее будет

Comment: @МаксимФисман и да возникновение[-1] не будет происходить, я малость отредактировал скрипт и такой момент больше не будет происходить

Comment: Не совсем понял, как вы отредактировали скрипт, но -1 элемент массива в C# не существует: [проверочка](https://ideone.com/J9u4C3), но если у вас происходит ошибка с массивом, разве можно заявлять, что проблема не в этом?

Comment: @МаксимФисман ошибка в отображении спрайтов не по порядку, если я уберу боковые спрайты все будет работать, да и с ними все работает, просто порядок спрайтов у объектов неправильный

Comment: @МаксимФисман хорошо,если -1 не существует то как получать последний элемент массива?

Comment: Последний элемент массива `ar` в C# можно получить так `ar[ar.Length-1]`. Еще пишут, что в новых версиях есть модное `ar[^1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@МаксимФисман пишет по делу, фраза `я/мы/люди не экстросенс/ы` или что-то типа `экстросенс в отпуске` рядовая. Введи `экстросенс` в поиск по SO. Это твой косяк.

Второй косяк в том, что ты посмотрел на ошибку, как баран на новые ворота. Текст ошибки `Index out of range` довольно однозначен, там даже указано на какой строчке и кликнув по ошибке, тебе это место покажут. На крайний случай ошибку можно была тупо загуглить.

`ShopController` должен выглядеть так:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ShopController : MonoBehaviour {
    
    // все поля только для внутреннего пользования и должны быть private
    [SerializeField] private Sprite[] _sprites;
    [SerializeField] private Image[] _images;
    private int _currentIndex = 1;
    
    // это называется свойство, похоже на метод, но без аргументов и содержит только get и/или set
    public int CurrentIndex  {
        get => _currentIndex;
        set {
            if (_currentIndex != value) {
                _currentIndex = value;
                UpdateIndex ();
            }
        }
    }

    // это исключительно событийная, а не постоянная история и никакого Update тут быть не должно, тем более с GetComponent
    private void UpdateIndex () {
        if (_images != null && _sprites != null && _images.Length > 0 && _sprites.Length > 0)) {
            ImageSetSprite(0, _currentIndex-1);
            ImageSetSprite(1, _currentIndex);
            ImageSetSprite(2, _currentIndex+1);
        }
    }

    private void ImageSetSprite (int imageIndex, int spriteIndex) {
        if (imageIndex < _images.Length) {
            while (spriteIndex >= _sprites.Length)
                spriteIndex -= _sprites.Length;
            while (spriteIndex < 0)
                spriteIndex += _sprites.Length;
            _images[imageIndex].sprite = _sprites[spriteIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ClickChanger : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private ShopController _controller;
    
    // у событий клика можно указывать одинарные аргументы
    //  +1/-1 соответственно
    public void Click (int change) {
        if (_controller != null)
            _controller.CurrentIndex += change;
    }
}
```

Comment: попробовал взять ваш код, подсвечивает красным ) на первой строчке апдейт индекса

Comment: Писал в браузере, опечатка, уже исправил. Можно было и догадаться, что там должно быть 0,1,2. Опять как баран на новые ворота. Текст как я понял по скорости ответа, ты даже не читал...

Comment: проблема почти решена за исключением одного момента - два объекта - центральный и правый меняют свой спрайт одинаково

Comment: Если уж эту даунскую опечатку, ты сам не найдёшь, тебе ничего не поможет.

Comment: нашел в чем косяк, и у 0 и у 2 стоит минус, нужен плюс

Comment: Молодец, бери пирожок с полочки, пометь пост как ответ на тему и положи пирожок обратно .

Comment: `положи пирожок обратно` - тролль100:) А почему `_sprites`, `_images`, а не `sprites`,`images`? Это какой-то стандарт? Они вроде не используются в свойствах и т.д.?

Comment: @МаксимФисман, стандарт найминга для приватных полей `private naming convention c#`. `C# Design Guidelines` от самих майкрасофт, что бы введя `_` сразу видел все внутренние поля. Операционные скобки `{ }`, я упорото ставлю, как в других языках, это не guideline , но нас таких ~17%

Comment: @МаксимФисман, `{ }`, фигурные. На тему не простовления тоже ведутся споры. Кармак упорото говорил, что ставить обязательно, но вроде сошлись на там, что если они есть в `if`, то должны быть и в `else` и на оборот, но и на это мне тоже пофиг . Стараюсь соблюдаю только базовые стандарты кода, нормальный человеческий нейминг, что-бы сам спустя время читал, без фейспалма и другой человек мог читать без желания пристрелить придурка, что это высрал (спустя месяц/ы ты сам и есть этот другой).

Comment: Может все же упорно вместо упорото?

Comment: @МаксимФисман, упорно, это когда ты что-то делаешь, а упорото это, когда ты как баран упираешься, что бы что-то не делать/ делать иначе. Поэтому упорото! В этом вопросе я баран .